# Font-size affecting next DIV positioing

Tags: html, css

I've come across this strange problem whereby the `font-size` in one `div` somehow effects the positioning of the next `div`. My code is:

```
<div class="first">
  1
</div>  
<div class="second">
  2
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.first{
    border: 1px blue solid;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 47px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 105px;
}

.second{
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 80px;
    width: 105px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

The second `div` is not horizontally aligned with the first `div`.

The jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/906b8fef/). If I remove the font-size, they both align horizontally. Why is this happening?

Comment: Use CSS: '.first {float: left;}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change The**  `vertical-align` `value` is **default** `baseline`

Hi now define your `first` and `second` class `vertical-align:top`  as like this

```
.first,.second{vertical-align:top;}
```

Demo

```css
.first{
    border: 1px blue solid;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 47px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 105px;
}

.second{
    border: 1px red solid;
    height: 80px;
    width: 105px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.first, .second{vertical-align:top;}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  1
</div><div class="second">
  2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the **baselines change** when you change the `font-size` or `height`. Give `vertical-align` in your CSS:

```
.first, .second {vertical-align: top;}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.first {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 47px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 105px;
}
.second {
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 80px;
  width: 105px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.first,
.second {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  1
</div>
<div class="second">
  2
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pgrwg0dw/**